# NodeJS headers on Windows are not installed automatically

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I have used NodeJS installers from the official site https://nodejs.org/en/.
For Linux it is just an archive and for Windows it is a .msi file.

The problem is that on Linux the unpacked archive contains include/node directory with uv.h, v8.h and most other famous headers, but on Windows the include directory does not appear after the installation with .msi.

I tried to use the command "npm install node-gyp", but it did not install the headers. After more deep googling I found that many people somehow have C:\Users\UserName\.node-gyp directory with all headers there, but I don't have it.

Questions:

- How to install the "complete" (containing headers) node-gyp on Windows?
- Why "npm install node-gyp" does not do it?

P. S: Also found that some people get it by "git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node". Really I should use this ugly way and copy manually the headers from the cloned project into my home?? I supposed, .msi or "npm install node-gyp" should do all the job.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround with using of headers from "git clone"-ed "node\deps" worked.
However, several days after I found the proper solution which is to run the command

```
node-gyp configure
```

This command wrote me in the log some interesting output:

```
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-headers.tar.gz
```

So, the headers are actually available on the official web-site https://nodejs.org/en/download/, but diligently hidden in the "All download options" menu item below on the page.

In the end "node-gyp configure" creates that famous directory C:\Users\UserName\.node-gyp\x.x.x with the "include\node" subdirectory inside it and the downloaded headers get located there with the proper structure.